# How to clear Windows/Wine's AppData on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, games

I am playing undertale and other games using wine to run them. How can I delete the equivalent of Wine's "AppData" to clear the data for these games.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to installed wintricks app, in this app you can delete wine spesific software or game.to install wintricks using terminal type sudo apt-get install winetricks.